# Issue in drag and drop in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I have a image and blank linear layout , when i drag button linear layout also move . I need to drag and drop button on linear layout and linear layout should be fixed position .

My Android XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewRequestDriver"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ballItem"
                    android:layout_width="50sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayoutItem"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"                   
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvItems"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="btnAdd_Click"
            android:text="Add New Item" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Code is :-

```
package com.beanie.example;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.beanie.example.BusinessObjects.Item;
import com.beanie.example.provider.ItemAdapter;
import com.beanie.example.BusinessManager.ItemManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class Dashboard extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
int windowwidth;
int windowheight;
private ItemAdapter ia;
Context context=null;
List<Item> items = null;
ProgressDialog signInProgress = null;
public Handler h = new Handler();
private LinearLayout linearlayout1;
private LayoutParams layoutParams ;
private LayoutParams layoutParams1 ;
int x_cord;
int y_cord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);


    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    ImageView ball= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ballItem);
    ball.setOnTouchListener(this);

    linearlayout1= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutItem);   


}   


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.ballItem:
        ImageView ball= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ballItem);
        layoutParams = (LayoutParams) ball.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:               
            ball.setAlpha(255);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
             y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();

            if(x_cord>windowwidth){x_cord=windowwidth;}
            if(y_cord>windowheight){y_cord=windowheight;}
            x_cord= x_cord -25;
            y_cord=y_cord - 230;
            layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord ;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord ;
            ball.setAlpha(45);
            ball.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;          
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:             

            layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord ;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;

            ImageView ball1= new ImageView(context);
            Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            animation.setDuration(5000);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            ball1.setImageBitmap(bm);
            ball1.setAnimation(animation);          
            ball1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            linearlayout1.addView(ball1);
            animation=null;

            EditText tv= new EditText(context);
            tv.setWidth(200);
            tv.setHint("TextBox 1");


            linearlayout1.addView(tv);
            EditText tv1= new EditText(context);
            tv1.setWidth(200);
            tv1.setHint("TextBox 2");


            //slide from top and bottom
            AnimUtils.setLayoutAnim_slidedownfromtop(linearlayout1, context);

            layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
            layoutParams.topMargin =  0;
            ball.setAlpha(255);
            ball.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            break;
        default : break;
        }            

    }
    return true;
}


}
```

Please suggest me usable link or modification in my code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below threads ,There are some good example for drag and drop a view :

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

Thanks

Comment: on first link , i have checkout it early , I have written comment on his post early regarding problem , please check my comment .

Answer (score 1):

Add `</LinearLayout>` at the last of xml file.

At last following should be presented for closing the layouts...

```
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry for missing tag , i have modified my question .

Comment: when i drag image button for dropping it on linear layout , the size of linear layout will reduce . I want to fixed size of linear layout when i drop image on it.

Comment: check screenshot https://plus.google.com/photos/112023949188480554415/albums/5698157231975301297?authkey=CNbH9sTNoLTE-QE

Comment: U should be try it by coding in xml file. Not by drag and drop method.